# Selenium Webdriver Classes Information(javadoc)

Tags: selenium, javadoc

Usually if I drag my mouse over any class we can details in Java IDE though but when same is done over WebDriver no information comes up; what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You may receive information only for classes and methods which included in official docs by link -`https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/`

[image: eclipse]

[image: url]

**Added**:
Check this property in IDE. In Eclipse IDE find `window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` - JDK must be installed as default!

[image: 3]

Comment: I am not even able to see above information after mouse hover

Comment: What version WebDriver you use? Do you use maven for project?

Comment: Added explanation in answer.